# How to modify an existing Joomla template to Joomla 3.x template?

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I am a beginner in Joomla! 
I have to upgrade a Joomla 2.5.x version site to the latest version of Joomla. 
I've checked the compatibility of all the existing components/modules/plugins of version 2.5.19 and they are all compatible in Joomla 3.x. 
The only problem is the template. 
I just don't know how to procceed and where to start from to modify it.

This are some of the lines of my **templateDetails.xml**:

```
<extension version="2.5" type="template" client="site">
    <name>Harpo</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
...
<files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <folder>css/</folder>
        <folder>images/</folder>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
        <filename>error.php</filename>
    </files>
    <images>
        <filename>template_thumbnail.png</filename>
    </images>
...
<positions>
        <position>newsflash</position>
        <position>hornav</position>
        <position>breadcrumbs</position>
        <position>banner</position>
        <position>left</position>
        <position>right</position>
        <position>top</position>
        <position>user1</position>
        <position>user2</position>
        <position>user3</position>
        <position>user4</position>
        <position>user5</position>
        <position>footer</position>
        <position>syndicate</position>
        <position>debug</position>
    </positions>

</extension>
```

And this are some of the lines of my index.php file :

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $app->getCfg( 'live_site' ); ?>templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/favicon.ico"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
<link href="<?php echo $app->getCfg( 'live_site' ); ?>templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<!-- <link href="css/template_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/> -->
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<meta name="verify-v1" content="PynT0gVSXBh484xuIjQakd0YZS+sHAYmOK+CRTa1aJI=" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $app->getCfg( 'live_site' ); ?>templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/flashobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-32944659-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
     })();

    jQuery.noConflict();
...
...
...
<body>
<div class="out">
    <div class="main">
    <!--Toparea Start-->
        <div class="top">
          <div class="logo_space">
              <div class="boxlogin"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="header">
            <img src="<?php echo $app->getCfg( 'live_site' ); ?>templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/img_header.jpg" alt="sfondo_header" align="top" style="float:left;"  />
            <div id="flash" style="float:right; width:550px; height:132px;"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var fo = new FlashObject("<?php 
                    $flashPath = $app->getCfg( 'live_site' )."templates/".$this->template."/flash/animazione.swf";
                    echo $flashPath; 
                ?>", "Menu", "550", "132", "8", "#FFFFFF", "transparent");
                fo.write("flash");
            </script>

            <!-- <img src="<?php echo $app->getCfg( 'live_site' ); ?>templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/img_headerright.jpg" alt="sfondo_header" align="top" style="float:right;" width="550" height="132"  /> -->
            <!-- <div class="boxlogin"></div> -->
        </div>

        <div class="topmenu">
            <?php if ($this->countModules( "top" )) { ?>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" />
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
...
...
...
```

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: What exactly do you need to update in the template? Hard to tell without knowing any specifics. There might be multiple code snippets that require changing or possible nothing

Comment: as @Lodder said, There might be multiple code snippets that require changing or possible nothing. Few weeks ago i updated a Joomla website, and i have problems with some components, but the template worked like a charm. so, what you should do is to update the site (in a test enviroment, if you want), and the address any specific error that you may get, if any.

Comment: I've edit my question ... as I said I just don't know where to start and what to check first ...I also tried to upgrade the site and the back end part was ok but the front end showed errors

Comment: You need to modify your CSS, your index should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok having looked at your code, here are a few things.

Firstly, you XML file is fine and doesn't require any changing.

To import jQuery in noConflict mode and ensure it is only done once, you should replace this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

with this:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); // this is PHP so wrap it in PHP tags
```

Once done, you can remove this code: `jQuery.noConflict();`

To get values from the configuration.php file, don't use `$app->getCfg()` as it's deprecated. Instead use, `$app->get()`. So in your case, replace this:

```
$app->getCfg('live_site')
```

with this

```
$app->get('live_site');
```

Other than that, I don't see any other issues with the code.

Comment: I just did the changes you suggested but I get an "500 - JHtmlBehavior::mootools not found"

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that code in your question, replace that line in your code with `JHtml::_('behavior.framework')`

Comment: Ok solved the issue by replacing JHtmlBehavior::mootools(); with JHtml::_('behavior.framework');